# My search results aren't consistent? Why is this?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am practicing with php mysql search results. The only problem I am getting is that the search isn't consistent in returning results.

Please visit:

weezy.co.uk/newresults.php

type in 'trainee' in the first search box at the top.
Sometimes the results show sometimes they don't. I don't get it?

my HTML search box code is:

```
<form action="newresults.php" method="post" name="form">
<input type="text" id="search" name="search" 
size="30" value="" style="background-    color:white; border: 
solid 1px #ffffff; height: 30px; font-size:19px; font-family: 
HelveticaNeue-Light; font-weight: 1;
vertical-align:9px;color:#151515" 
onfocus="if(this.value == ''){this.value = 
'';this.style.color='#363D42'}" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="search">
<div class="search1">
<input type="text" 
id="searchterm" name="searchterm"  size="25" value="" style="background- 
color:white;  border: 
solid 1px #ffffff; height: 30px; font-size:19px; font-family: 
HelveticaNeue-Light; font-            weight: 1;
vertical-align:9px;color:#151515" 
onfocus="if(this.value == ''){this.value = 
'';this.style.color='#363D42'}" />
</form>
```

php code:

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("", "", "");

if (!$conn) {
echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
exit;
}

{

$search = "%" . $_POST["search"] . "%";
$searchterm = "%" . $_POST["searchterm"] . "%";

}

if (!mysql_select_db("weezycouk_641290_db1")) {
echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT name,lastname,email 
    FROM   test_mysql
    WHERE  name LIKE '$search%' AND lastname LIKE '$searchterm%'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
exit;
}


while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';
echo '<div class="data1">';
echo $row["name"];
echo '</div>';
echo '<br>';
echo '<div class="data2">';
echo $row["lastname"];
echo '</div>';
echo '<br>';
echo '<div class="data3">';
echo $row["email"];
echo '</div>';
}

mysql_free_result($result);

?>
```

Thanks guys!

James

Comment: Please provide screenshots or elaborate on the search behavior. Providing a link to your website with the problem won't help anyone by the time the problem is solved.

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question, but I do know you should **always** use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://nl.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to prevent SQL injection attacks. Also see: http://nl.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Thnaks guys, basically i can type in trainee in the search and results will show. then i can do i type trainee in again and no results will show

Comment: Well I dont know exactly what is wrong, but what is remarkable is that theres a clear pattern: noshow - show - noshow - show - noshow etc... Is this all your code or is there a weird block around your php with a block like if(POST) etc...

Comment: no thats the whole php code. Is there anything you can suggest to help?

Comment: Well it can't be the *whole* code, because that code doesn't generate the page header. There must be some more code that calls `include` (if the PHP is an a seperate file). Please post a complete version of the whole file.

Comment: say I enter "trainee" in the first box, in `$search = "%" . $_POST["search"] . "%";` `$search` will evaluate to `"%trainee%"`. In SQL query will then become `"SELECT name,lastname,email FROM test_mysql WHERE  name LIKE '%trainee%%' AND lastname LIKE '%%%'";`. Won't that mean you end up searching for "trainee%"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your page loads with results, you also load a "Tags" sidebar with the question "Want the recruiters to find you?"  The input boxes in that sidebar are filled in with "Enter name" and "Enter chosen industry."  The "name" attribute on both those inputs is "search," so you are posting multiple fields named "search."

Just change the names on the inputs in your sidebar to fix this bug.  You should definitely sanitize the inputs (as others have noted), too.

Comment: I changed them but still having the same problem. When there are no search results shown and i enter text in the inputs it works and returns search results BUT if there are results shown and i enter text in the inputs above the 3rd column on the right disappears and no results show!?

Comment: You still have two inputs with name="search" on the page.

Comment: My bad, i forgot the iput at the bottom! Thanks very much guys! much appreciated!

Comment: Also one more thing! If i click on a search field and press enter with nothing in it, ALL the results show. How can this be stopped?

Comment: But now it does the same for when I enter information that isn't in the database. What is going on now?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it will solve your problem but you should construct the SQL query in this way:

```
$sql = '
   SELECT name,
      lastname,
      email, 
   FROM test_mysql
   WHERE name LIKE %' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']) . '%
      AND lastname LIKE %' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['searchterm']) . '%
';
```

If you would like to prevent displaying all rows in case user will not fill input values, use something like this:

```
function makeWhereLike($column, $inputValue)
{
   $wherePart = '';
   if ($inputValue) {
      $wherePart = $column . ' LIKE %' . mysql_real_escape_string($inputValue) . '% ';
   } else {
      $wherePart = $column . ' IS NULL ';
   }
   return $wherePart;
}

$sql = '
   SELECT name,
      lastname,
      email, 
   FROM test_mysql
   WHERE ' . makeWhereLike('name', $_POST['search']) . '
      AND ' . makeWhereLike('lastname', $_POST['searchterm']) . '
';
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I'm quite sure there is something wicked in the part of the JS code where you submit this form. I suggest you try to submit it by adding a traditional submit-button there and see what happens.</strike>

Every second time you're query echoes "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting", although it's not visible in results because it's printed in #ffffff.

Comment: I just got rid of all the js code and put a submit button on but still have the same problem. It seems when there is search results and I want to use the search fields it returns a blank page and gets rid of some of my html code (right column). But when there is no results it will return search results. So confusing! Why is this?

Comment: Did you do as Derek Kurth adviced? That should get you through.

Comment: But now it does the same for when I enter information that isn't in the database. What is going on now?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$sql = "SELECT name,lastname,email 
FROM   test_mysql
WHERE  name LIKE '%".$search."%' AND lastname LIKE '%".$searchterm."%'";
```