# How to stop search field returning all results when submitting empty search field?

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

If i click on my search field and submit it without entering any text all the data in my database is returned. How is this stopped so nothing happens?

Check out the site:

weezy.co.uk/newresults.php

Thanks!

James

```
 <?php

    $conn = mysql_connect("cust-mysql-123-02", "uwee_641290_0001", "La0%-Mr4");

    if (!$conn) {
    echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
    }

    {

      $search = "%" . $_POST["search"] . "%";
    $searchterm = "%" . $_POST["searchterm"] . "%";

    }

    if (!mysql_select_db("weezycouk_641290_db1")) {
    echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT name,lastname,email 
    FROM   test_mysql
    WHERE  name LIKE '%".$search."%' AND lastname LIKE '%".$searchterm."%'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
    }

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
    }


while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<div class="data1">';
    echo $row["name"];
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<div class="data2">';
    echo $row["lastname"];
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<div class="data3">';
    echo $row["email"];
    echo '</div>';
    }

    mysql_free_result($result);

    ?>
```

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa look at his previous questions for that; the [last one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888865/my-search-results-arent-consistent-why-is-this), for ex.

Comment: @DamienPirsy So you're saying me that, piece for piece, we are doing the whole application? :)

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa when I skimmed over the questions I thought the very same thing!

Answer (score 3):

you should check if it's empty before making a query:

```
if(empty($_POST['searchterm'])){
    //don't search and show an error message
}else{
   //proceed as normal, do the query
}
```

otherwise you might end up making a query like:

```
WHERE name LIKE('%%')
```

which is really expensive and returns all your database rows

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this (imo) is to have a simple javascript checking if the input is blank or not.

Comment: You should not rely solely on javascript for validation. It should be used to make the user experience better, but data should _always_ be validated on the backend.

Comment: I agree. Simple Javascript, mixed with Nicola's empty if-statement would work best here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to disable the submit button on the client side whenever your search box is empty.

You could do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#searchBox').keyup(function() 
   {
      if($(this).val() == '')
      {
        $('#searchButton').attr('disabled', true);
      }
      else
      {
        $('#searchButton').removeAttr('disabled');
      }

   });
});
```

where your html is like:

```
<input type='text' id="searchBox" />
<input type='button' id='searchButton' value='search' disabled/>
```

Make sure to validate on the server side as Nicola has indicated.

Answer (score 0):

It is always wise to do some `front end` using `javascript/Jquery`. form validation where you are prompting users to input something.

Once you are done you may also check on the back end using the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['searchterm'])){
    // search for the results.
}else{
   // do nothing or show proper message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing some problems in the above code. So the following improved version of the above code works just fine:

```
<form action="searchengine.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" id = "searchbox" name="searchterm" placeholder="Search here">
<input type="submit" id = "searchbutton" value="Search" style="display:none;">
</center>
<script src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#searchbox').keyup(function()
{
if($(this).val() == '')
{
$('#searchbutton').hide();
}
else
{
$('#searchbutton').show();
}

});
});

</script>
```